# Action 'init' function doesn't return variable

Tags: actions, variables, init

I have a function which checks if $_POST is set (a form which submits to the same page). I need to have it initialized before the page is loaded because the function will do a header **redirect** if the validation goes through without errors.

So the function is registered like this:

```
add_action('init', 'signup_validate_insert');
```

And the function itself starts like this:

```
function signup_validate_insert(){
    $errors = false;
        if (!empty($_POST['submit_msg'])) {
         //validation and stuff
        }
```

And if there are errors, it returns the errors array:

```
return $errors;
```

When the submit button is pressed, the function registers it as it should, and goes through the validation. I have checked to see that the errors array is being filled in the function. But the variable is not returned! (although I have set "return $errors")

The variable is supposed to be returned to the template, where the errors can be displayed if $errors are not empty.

I have tried switching to `add_filter` instead, with the same result.

So the question is really how to be able to return this variable - hope you can help!

Comment: Per the docs on [`add_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/), it will *always* return `true`.

Answer (score 1):

actions do not "return" values. If you need to do some heavy computation that you want to avoid redoing at a later stage then you should store the value at a global variable (pure global, static or a field in an object depending on your favorite coding style).

Answer (score 0):

See my updated answer, now i tried as per your condition and my url is like now

```
    http://www.example.com/?query=yes

add_action('init', 'my_cookie');

add_action('init', 'signup_validate_insert');

function signup_validate_insert() {
    if(isset($_REQUEST['query'])) {     
        $errors = 'my_error';
        setcookie("my_cookie", $errors, time()+3600);       
        wp_redirect(home_url('shortcode-9/'));
        die();
    }
}

function my_cookie() {
    if(isset($_COOKIE['my_cookie'])) {

        echo $_COOKIE['my_cookie'];
    }
}

    it is for me working nice. am i right? Reply your thoughts.
```

Comment: How do you return the $errors variable?

Comment: Yes, that could be a workaround...this is not easy. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: this time i set cookie working like a charm. you try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, unless you specify a POST submission, it will use GET as default.
So using `$_POST` will return empty. If you use `$_GET` it will work. I often use `$_REQUEST` to avoid this issue.

As Pat comments, `add_action` always returns true. So if you need to return erros to show this in the form, then you should consider sending the form via ajax.

```
function signup_validate_insert()
{
    $errors = false;
    if (!empty($_POST['submit_msg'])) {
      // Do your validation
    } else {
      $errors = true;
    }

    //If no errors are found, procede with form submition.
    if(!$errors){
      wp_redirect( $location, $status );
      exit;
    } else {          
      /*
        If errors are found you have 3 options:
        1. Store the errors in a db table and retrieve the errors in the page template  
        2. Store the errors in a cookie
        3. Redirect page to form and put the erros in the URL

      */
    }
}
```

I would however strongly recommend you to submit the for via jQuery and return errors if any. If not, redirect data to the page to ahndle the form submission.

```
var formData = $('form').serialize()

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: formData ,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: Maybe I was unclear in some way. The errors array is being filled in the validation process. So if $_POST['submit_msg'] is not empty, the validation starts, one or more errors are added to the errors array, and then I would like to make this variable available to the template where the form is. I can't find any information on this.

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: Yes, it seems that jQuery is the only possible way.. even if I put the validation code inside the template, I can't do a header redirect from there, since part of the page has already been loaded.

Comment: Unless I have no other choice, I always post form data using jQuery / Ajax. I don't believe storing the data in a global variable is a good way.